# mxGPUGetDimensions returns an array with zeroes in between the dimension sizes

Tags: c, matlab, cuda, mex

So I pass a 5 by 6 (host) matrix to my mex function. (Part of) my code:

```
const mxGPUArray* A;

A=mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]);
const mwSize* img_size =  mxGPUGetDimensions(A);
const int M=img_size[0];
const int N=img_size[1];
const int O=img_size[2];
const int P=mxGPUGetNumberOfDimensions (A);

mexPrintf("\n %i %i %i %i \n",M,N,O,P);
```

My output is:
    5 0 6 2

And if I set P to be img_size[3] I get 0, img_size[0 to 3]= 5,0,6,0

even though the number of dimensions according to:

```
mxGPUGetNumberOfDimensions (A);
```

is

```
2
```

[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/distcomp/mxgpugetdimensions.html) doesn't mention anything about this. Why is this? Is mwsize actually not equivalent with size_t or something? Does it refer to the memory pitch? Am I actually using a flat 4D array?

Comment: Is this on a 64bit or 32bit platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to preface this by saying that I have *never* worked with the Matlab mex interface before, however....

What is clearly happening is that there is a mismatch in size between what `mxGPUGetDimensions` is returning, and what you code is using for `mwSize`. The result you get [5, 0, 6, 0] is actually [5,6] if the return values were 64 bit integers (size_t on a 64 bit platform for example), rather than 32 bit. The [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/apiref/mwsize.html) for `mwSize` says the following:

> By default, mwSize is equivalent to int in C. When using the mex
>   -largeArrayDims switch, mwSize is equivalent to size_t in C.

Because I know absolutely nothing about Matlab, I can't tell you how to fix this beyond (a) making sure that your compiler/toolchain is building 64 bit code, and (b) try using that `largeArrayDims` option.

If none of that works, I would suggest contacting Mathworks support. Something is clearly broken in either your build environment or Matlab itself.

Comment: Your comment gave me a clue! I'll accept your answer though because it's much more elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I added the

```
-largeArrayDims
```

switch, and now the values are correct, i.e.

```
img_size[0]
```

and

```
img_size[1]
```

correspond with the correct values.